# Laravel: Select Distinct on one to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So i have this relationship between my two Models

**Product.php**

```
public function photos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Photo');
}
```

**Photo.php**

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
}
```

What I want to do is to get only one photo for each product. this is my query

```
$my_ads = DB::table('products as p')
                    ->join('photos as pic','p.id','=','pic.product_id')
                    ->select(DB::RAW('DISTINCT(pic.product_id)'),'p.*','pic.file_path')
                    ->get();
```

The result I am getting in this query is repeating. If my first product has five photos, the collection will have 5 instances of the same product with different photos.

How can I achieve that for every product I can only have one photo? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In eloquent, you can do it easily.

```
Product::with([
    'photos' => function($q){
        $q->take(1);
    }
])->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not doing this the Eloquent way?

```
App\Product::with('photos')->get();
```

This will retrieve all your products, with their photos and no product will be repeated.